# How to play media files sequentially without visible break?

Tags: javascript, audio, video, streaming, media

*I've worded my title, and tags in a way that should be searchable for both video and audio, as this question isn't specific to one. My specific case only concerns audio though, so my question body will be written specific to that.*

---

First, the big picture:

I'm sending audio to multiple P2P clients who will connect and disconnect a random intervals. The audio I'm sending is a stream, but each client only needs the part of the stream from whence they connected. Here's how I solved that:

- Every {timeout} (e.g. 1000ms), create a new audio blob

  - Blob will be a full audio file, with all metadata it needs to be playable
- As soon as a blob is created, convert to array buffer (better browser support), and upload to client over WebRTC (or WebSockets if they don't support)

That works well. There is a delay, but if you keep the timeout low enough, it's fine.

---

Now, my question:

**How can I play my "stream" without having any audible delay?**

I say stream, but I didn't implement it using the Streams API, it is a queue of blobs, that gets updated every time the client gets new data.

I've tried a lot of different things like:

- Creating a BufferSource, and merging two blobs (converted to audioBuffers) then playing that
- Passing an actual stream from Stream API to clients instead of blobs
- Playing blobs sequentially, relying on `ended` event
- Loading next blob while current blob is playing

Each has problems, difficulties, or still results in an audible delay.

Here's my most recent attempt at this:

```
let firstTime = true;
const chunks = [];
Events.on('audio-received', ({ detail: audioChunk }) => {
    chunks.push(audioChunk);

    if (firstTime && chunks.length > 2) {
        const currentAudio = document.createElement("audio");
        currentAudio.controls = true;
        currentAudio.preload = 'auto';
        document.body.appendChild(currentAudio);
        currentAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(chunks.shift());
        currentAudio.play();

        const nextAudio = document.createElement("audio");
        nextAudio.controls = true;
        nextAudio.preload = 'auto';
        document.body.appendChild(nextAudio);
        nextAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(chunks.shift());

        let currentAudioStartTime, nextAudioStartTime;

        currentAudio.addEventListener("ended", () => {
            nextAudio.play()
            nextAudioStartTime = new Date();
            if (chunks.length) {
                currentAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(chunks.shift());
            }
        });
        nextAudio.addEventListener("ended", () => {
            currentAudio.play()
            currentAudioStartTime = new Date();
            console.log(currentAudioStartTime - nextAudioStartTime)
            if (chunks.length) {
                nextAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(chunks.shift());
            }
        });

        firstTime = false;
    }
});
```

The `audio-received` event gets called every ~1000ms. This code works; it plays each "chunk" after the last one was played, but on Chrome, there is a ~300ms delay that's very audible. It plays the first chunk, then goes quiet, then plays the second, so on. On Firefox the delay is 50ms.

Can you help me?

I can try to create a reproducible example if that would help.

Comment: What format is the audio? Is it in a container (eg aac inside an `.m4a` file) or just raw mp3 / aac frames? I see you mentioned _"Blob will be a full audio file, with all metadata"_ well in such cases I think the (MPEG?) decoder has to stop and flush the old metadata and then re-process the new metadata before playbac (hence the subtle delay). Is it possible to just feed mp3 bytes? I don't use WebRTC but had similar task for Windows desktop coding.

Comment: Sending blobs over WebRTC is pretty dumb. I'm basically recreating functionality, since you can send real media streams webrtc. Thing is, I'm doing it this way because the clients can connect and disconnect at random intervals. I believe if I use a media stream over webrtc, then I'd have to restart the stream or something, every time a client connects. Which would suck, since the all the currently connected clients would also need to get that new stream. I might be wrong about the restarting tho.

Comment: @VC.One This is basically my code for sending audio. It just uses the browser default for encoding. https://gist.github.com/ratskin/47c8d98c9269a2587650a49b6cc1fa95. But I don't think it's an encoding delay, as I'm using Array.shift() to get the first element. The chunks array will already have data when ever I shift(). The delay is happening when playing the audio

Comment: Use MP3 (no container) if possible. MP3 was designed for streaming you see. An mp3 file is just a bunch of multiple audio data frames. Each frame is a few milliseconds so you need to join (concat) around 40 frames to make 1 sec of audio before sending to decoder. To seek or play a different section of audio you simply provide frame bytes that represent that section to hear... If possible show code to recreate your problem and I'll try to advise.